# Windows обрезает hostname

Tags: windows, netbios

Вот возникла такая проблема, Windows Server 2016 обрезает длинный hostname, из 19 символов делает 15, как я понял это из-за обратной подержки NetBIOS, можно ли как то обойти это ограничение, пусть даже путём отключения компонентов которые требуют 15 символов.

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Это ограничение протокола. NetBIOS-имя имеет длину 16 байт, из которых один байт занят под тип ресурса. А hostname - это именно NetBIOS hostname. Формируйте имя нужной длины в DNS и установите требуемое соответствие.

Comment: Можно поменять через linux-утилиту `ocs-chnthn`. Но после этого винда уходит в синьку и бесконечную перезагрузку. Так что поддержу @Akina про DNS.

Comment: Понятно, я где-то так и подозревал, но думал вдруг есть какой-то костыль.